# Perl objects error: Can't locate object method via package only happens with perl 5.10 not perl 5.18

Tags: perl, sqlite

I am trying to use some OO Perl code here:

https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-hive

I tried it on an Ubuntu VM with perl 5.18, and it works like a charm:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-perl libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl libcapture-tiny-perl sqlite3

git clone https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-hive.git

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ensembl-hive/scripts

init_pipeline.pl Bio::EnsEMBL::Hive::PipeConfig::AnyCommands_conf -password foobar -hive_driver sqlite -pipeline_db -user foo -user foo
```

But then I tried the same on an HPC system running CentOS with perl 5.10, and I get this error at the end of the last command:

```
Can't locate object method "name" via package "Bio::EnsEMBL::Hive::Meadow::LSF" at /data/home/user/ensembl-hive/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/Hive/Valley.pm line 64.
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: That's weird as `sub name` is declared in `LSF.pm`. Seems like the package hasn't been loaded at all.

Comment: Could you try adding a line `warn "Exception in 'require $meadow_class': $@" if $@;` after [this line](https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-hive/blob/version/2.3/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/Hive/Valley.pm#L63) and see if it gives some hint about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @srvsh, adding the warn statement in your comment uncovered the real issue:

`Exception in 'require Bio::EnsEMBL::Hive::Meadow::LSF': Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (...`

I installed Time::Piece and then it works.

Comment: Please submit a patch to the package maintainer.  Unchecked exception handling is EVIL.  Something like will do nicely: local $@; eval "require $meadow_class; 1" or do { die $@ || "Unknown error loading '$meadow_class'";

Comment: Time::Piece has been a core module since Perl 5.10, so it should have already been installed. Did you mess with `@INC` at all?